# Why is typescript converting number to string?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown with these values below and when I first use the initial value it's undefined. But then after I change to '30 min' then back to 'Any' the property I'm using as the ngModel gets set from 30 to 'undefined'! It gets set to a string?

The actual property looks like this below - I didn't realize typescript would convert it like that?

```
length: number;
```

where my dropdown is here

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="length">Length</label>
  <select class="form-control w-100" id="length" name="length" [(ngModel)]="eventParams.length">
    <option *ngFor="let length of lengthList" [value]="length.value">
      {{length.display}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

```js
  lengthList = [
    {value: undefined, display: 'Any'},
    {value: 30, display: '30 min'},
    {value: 45, display: '45 min'},
    {value: 60, display: '60 min'},
    {value: 90, display: '90 min'}
  ];
```

Comment: What is the problem of converting it to 'undefined'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption#properties) documentation

> Value attribute tracks simple string values bound to the option element. For objects,
> use the ngValue input binding.

Use ngValue attribute it will work as expected.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="length">Length</label>
      <select class="form-control w-100" id="length" name="length" [(ngModel)]="eventParams.length">
        <option *ngFor="let length of lengthList" [ngValue]="length.value">
          {{length.display}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
```